# How to fill colors in piechart using  Pychart

Tags: python, charts

I am using python Pychart.
I have done the following code to generate pie chart:

```
from pychart import *
import sys

data = [("foo", 10),("bar", 20), ("baz", 30), ("ao", 40)]
theme.get_options()    
ar = area.T(size=(150,150), legend=legend.T(),
            x_grid_style = None, y_grid_style = None)

plot = pie_plot.T(data=data, arc_offsets=[0,0,0,0],
                  shadow = (0, 0, fill_style.gray50),
                  label_offset = 25,
                  arrow_style = arrow.a3)
ar.add_plot(plot)
ar.draw()
```

It generates the pie chart with gray scale.
Instead of gray-scale, I want different colors in pie chart.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `theme.use_color = True` before the call to get_options().

For the theme documentation:

> **use_color**
>
> The default value of this variable is
>   False. If the value is True, PyChart
>   colorizes some of the default objects.
>   If the value is False, PyChart uses
>   gray scale for the color of these
>   objects.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like pychart haven't been updated since 2006, I would recommend that you have a look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), perhaps *the* best plotting library for python.

Pie-chart example [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the filling colors with the `fill_styles` argument (len of this list should be the same as the data length):

```
from pychart import *
import sys

data = [("foo", 10),("bar", 20), ("baz", 30), ("ao", 40)]
theme.get_options()    
ar = area.T(size=(150,150), legend=legend.T(),
            x_grid_style = None, y_grid_style = None)

plot = pie_plot.T(data=data, arc_offsets=[0,0,0,0],
                  fill_styles = [fill_style.red, fill_style.blue, fill_style.green, fill_style.yellow],
                  shadow = (0, 0, fill_style.gray50),
                  label_offset = 25,
                  arrow_style = arrow.a3)
ar.add_plot(plot)
ar.draw()
```

and it will work in colors :)

[List of colors](http://home.gna.org/pychart/doc/module-fill-style.html)